# Javascript | How to print second element with using classname

Tags: javascript

How to print second element using classname "nameAnswer".
It says: **undefined** Why?

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="dog"></h1>
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="cat"></h1>
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="fish"></h1>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var count = document.getElementsByClassName("nameAnswer").length;
if(count>1){
var answ = document.getElementsByClassName('nameAnswer'[2]).value;
alert(answ);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need slight change in your code

```
var count = document.getElementsByClassName("nameAnswer").length;
if(count>1){
var answ = document.getElementsByClassName('nameAnswer')[2].getAttribute('value')
alert(answ);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
var count = document.getElementsByClassName("nameAnswer").length;
if(count>1){
  var answ = count[2].value;
  alert(answ);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `[2]` after the parentheses. Or just do the following:

```
var nameAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("nameAnswer");
var count = nameAnswers.length;
if(count > 1){
    var answer = nameAnswers[2].value;
    alert(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const childNumber = 2

const el = document.querySelector(`.nameAnswer:nth-child(${childNumber})`)

const val = el ? el.getAttribute('value') : '-'

console.log(val)
```

```html
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="dog"></h1>
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="cat"></h1>
<h1 class="nameAnswer" value="fish"></h1>
```